# Record changes for removed macro in dtx

Tags: dtx, changes

Following the advice in [How to Package Your LATEX Package](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/dtxtut/dtxtut.pdf) by Scott Pakin I am recording changes to a package I maintain, similar to the following:

```
\RecordChanges

\begin{macro}{\somemacro}
\changes{0.1}{2018/01/01}{Added a shiny new macro}
\begin{macrocode}
…
\end{macrocode}
\end{macro}

\PrintChanges
```

However, if I eventually want to remove the `\somemacro` command in version 2.0 of the package, I would like to be able to retain the old change history but not show the macro in the package otherwise.

Is there some way to hide the `\begin{macro}` from rendering the macro name in the sidebar, or remove the `\begin{macro}` entirely and manually specify the macro that the change lines should be under in the changelog (so that they don't just show up under the general one)?

Comment: I think you can replace `\begin{macro}` by `\begingroup\edef\saved@macroname{\string\somemacro}%`  (untested as you didn't supply a test file....)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, any changes inside that \begingroup\endgroup don't seem to show up at all (not even in the "general" section of the change log)

Comment: The DTX format really dates from the days when one wouldn't actually remove the lines at all, but rather comment them out. That goes with the fact that in (La)TeX _someone_ will depend on every single internal macro you have ... so you probably have to keep some record of all of them in the sources.

Comment: @SamWhited macro doesn't do anything much other than print the name and set up that indexing so something along those lines will work, but as I say above no example no test.